# Compiling Chromium hangs on sync projects, throws "git -c","Unknown option:-c" error

Tags: compilation, chromium

The full error trace:

```
1>At revision 212822.
1>Syncing projects:   0% ( 0/ 3) 
19>________ running 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress --template=/home/hellmagic/depot_tools/git-templates https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/angle.git /home/hellmagic/chromium/src/third_party/_gclient_angle_dx11_7W8bH8' in '/home/hellmagic/chromium'
19>Unknown option: -c
19>usage: git [--version] [--exec-path[=GIT_EXEC_PATH]] [--html-path]
19>           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects]
19>           [--bare] [--git-dir=GIT_DIR] [--work-tree=GIT_WORK_TREE]
19>           [--help] COMMAND [ARGS]
17>_____ src/third_party/accessibility-developer-tools at ad5df9a5341d38778658c90e4aa241c4ebe4e8aa
18>_____ src/third_party/android_tools at e9da75d5e88d3e122ac60ee1d642cdcc1acb2bd8
Error: Command git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress --template=/home/hellmagic/depot_tools/git-templates https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/angle.git /home/hellmagic/chromium/src/third_party/_gclient_angle_dx11_7W8bH8 returned non-zero exit status 129 in /home/hellmagic/chromium
```

I really can't understand where the error in "git -c" comes from. I have found all the files I think maybe cause the error, but there's no useful information. If someone knows about this, please give me a hand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've Just encounted this error while trying to install mod_pagespeed on Slackware.

The only solution i found was to edit the gclient_scm.py file in the depot_tools/ folder.

Be sure to make a backup of gclient_scm.py before editting, just to be safe.

Make the following changes to your gclient_scm.py file;

on line 288 you should find

```
fetch_cmd = [
  '-c', 'core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g', 'fetch', 'origin', '--prune']
```

Change this to

```
fetch_cmd = [
  'fetch', 'origin', '--prune']
```

Then on line 801 you will find

```
 cmd = ['clone'] + v + ['-c', 'core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g',
                           '--progress', '--mirror']
```

Change this to

```
 cmd = ['clone'] + v + [
                           '--progress', '--mirror']
```

then on line 849

```
clone_cmd = ['-c', 'core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g', 'clone', '--no-checkout',
             '--progress', '--template=%s' % template_path]
```

Change to

```
clone_cmd = ['clone', '--no-checkout',
             '--progress', '--template=%s' % template_path]
```

line 1051 needs changing from

```
fetch_cmd = ['-c', 'core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g', 'fetch', 'origin']
```

to

```
fetch_cmd = ['fetch', 'origin']
```

Once you have done this, save the file and that should work.

I'm not too sure if there is a better solution to this or what the purpose of core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g is but this worked for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking this up now: Add "return []" to DefaultIndexPackConfig near the end of depot_tools/gclient_utils.py

```
> diff -C 3 gclient_utils.py.original gclient_utils.py

*** gclient_utils.py.original   2014-07-01 21:47:56.295988677 -0700
--- gclient_utils.py            2014-07-01 21:49:16.764988592 -0700
***************
*** 1116,1121 ****
--- 1116,1122 ----

    Experiments suggest that higher values for pack.threads don't improve
    performance."""
+   return []
    cache_limit = DefaultDeltaBaseCacheLimit()
    result = ['-c', 'core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=%s' % cache_limit]
    if url in THREADED_INDEX_PACK_BLACKLIST:
```